# C++ functions of pointers to classes don't work?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm trying to generate a terrain using perlin noise, to improve the quality of the terrain, I want to use multiple noises at once. So I have written a class that should to that for me. Here are the hpp and cpp files:

```
#include "perlinNoise.hpp"

class MultiPerlinNoise: public PerlinNoise {
public:
    MultiPerlinNoise();

    std::vector<PerlinNoise*> perlinNoises;

    float octaveNoise(float x, float y);
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "multiPerlinNoise.hpp"

MultiPerlinNoise::MultiPerlinNoise():
PerlinNoise(0) {

}

float MultiPerlinNoise::octaveNoise(float x, float y) {
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for(int i = 0; i < perlinNoises.size(); i++)
        sum += perlinNoises[i]->octaveNoise(x, y);

    return sum;
}
```

The `PerlinNoise` class is a wrapper around the code for a octave peril noise I found on the internet. It looks like this:

```
#include "sivPerlinNoise.hpp"

class PerlinNoise {
public:
    PerlinNoise(unsigned int seed);

    float octaveNoise(float x, float y);

    float frequency;
    float multiplier;
    int octaves;
    unsigned int seed;
    float offset;

private:
    siv::PerlinNoise perlinNoise;
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "perlinNoise.hpp"

PerlinNoise::PerlinNoise(unsigned int seed):
perlinNoise(seed), frequency(2.0f), multiplier(1.0f), octaves(1), seed(seed), offset(0.0f) {

}

float PerlinNoise::octaveNoise(float x, float y) {
    return perlinNoise.octaveNoise(x / frequency, y / frequency, octaves) * multiplier + offset;
}
```

Now the problem is, that when I pass a pointer to my noise into my `map` class, the function always return `0.0f`. This is how the constructor of my map class looks like:

```
Map::Map(PerlinNoise *noise, Shader *shader, const RenderData *data):
noise(noise), shader(shader), data(data), texture("resources/textures/stones.png") {
    printf("%f\n", noise->octaveNoise(-(CHUNK_SIZE / 2.0f) + 0.0f, -(CHUNK_SIZE / 2.0f) + 0.0f));
    update(glm::vec3(0.0f));
}
```

When I don't use a pointer to my noise everything is working as it should. **How can this be fixed?**

Comment: I guess you just need to declare `octaveNoise` as [virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). Just to be sure: In the last piece of code `PerlinNoise *noise` is pointing to a `MultiPerlinNoise` right?

Comment: @churill Yes, the noise is in this case a `MultiPerlinNoise`. The `virtual` solved the problem. Would you please write this as answer so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `octaveNoise` as virtual, so the method can be overridden by inheriting classes:

```
class MultiPerlinNoise: public PerlinNoise {
public:
    MultiPerlinNoise();

    std::vector<PerlinNoise*> perlinNoises;

    virtual float octaveNoise(float x, float y);
};
```